# AS3 gotoAndPlay button

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this:

```
           123456789ABCDEF
```

Action 2..........o___Xa________Xo

Action.............a___X

Juego.............o_________oxxxX

Niveles...........o____oxxxX

Presentacion..oxxxX

Script in "Action" frame1 looks like this:

```
stop();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoNiveles);

function gotoNiveles(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("goto frame 6");
    gotoAndStop(6);
    /* line added to do it work properly
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoNiveles);
    */
}
```

Script in "Action2" frame6 look like this:

```
nivelButton1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoNivel1);

function gotoNivel1(event:MouseEvent):void
{

        trace("goto frame 11");
        gotoAndPlay(11);
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.technotupper.com"), "_blank");

}
```

It shows:

- "goto frame 6"
- "goto frame 11"
- "goto frame 6"

And it opens "www.technotupper.com", but it is not working as far as it is not showing frame 11 but going back to frame 6 and showing frame 6.

Thank you.

J. Pablo.

Comment: Is the button inside a movieclip, and are there 11 frames where the button is?

Comment: The button is on the stage at frame 5 (symbol button), there are 15 frames. 1 - 5 presentation, 6 - 10 button, 11 - 15 new screen.

Comment: On which frame you are writing the action?

Comment: Actions are at frames: 1 and 6. 
The one at frame 1 for click event on the stage jumps right to frame 6.
The one at frame 6 for click event on buttons does not jump to frame 11.

Comment: Ok, so that's the reason. Add a new layer above it and then write the action on frame 1 only. Or, at frame 6, remove the current button, copy the same button from library, name it something new and register the event listener with the new name.

Answer (score 0):

The mouse click event of the stage must be removed.

Just add "stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoNiveles);" after "gotoAndStop(6);"

I add it like a comment on the question.